# Is there a way to globally change title of all navigtion bar back button to "Back"

Tags: ios

It's tedious to change it in all view controller

Can I change it globally?

Comment: Maybe subclass UIViewController, implement it there and make all you ViewControllers of that type. Of course you would still have to touch every existing ViewController at least once.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 11):

What you can use is a category:

UINavigationItem+MyBackButton.h

```
@interface UINavigationItem (MyBackButton)

@end
```

UINavigationItem+MyBackButton.m

```
#import "UINavigationItem+MyBackButton.h"

@implementation UINavigationItem (MyBackButton)

-(UIBarButtonItem*)backBarButtonItem
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle: @"Back Button Text" 
                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target: nil action: nil];

    return [backButton autorelease];
}
@end
```

Add this two files to the project and you are done.
To be more efficient ivar and lazy loading should be added here.