# How to globally customize back button?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uiappearance

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804672/is-there-a-way-to-globally-change-title-of-all-navigtion-bar-back-button-to-bac), where the accepted answer describes a way to globally customize the `UINavigationController`'s back button, using this code in the implementation of a category named `UINavigationItem+MyBackButton.h`:

```
#import "UINavigationItem+MyBackButton.h"

@implementation UINavigationItem (MyBackButton)

-(UIBarButtonItem*)backBarButtonItem
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle: @"Back Button Text" 
                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target: nil action: nil];

    return [backButton autorelease];
}
@end
```

This code works fine for me as long as I only want to customize the title. When I want to get down and dirty and try to customize the background image, just nothing happens and I all I get the default back button showing the `title` of the previous `UIViewController` on the stack:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem
{
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 27); // CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 36);

    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] ;
    [backBarButton setTarget:nil];
    return backBarButton;
}
```

I also tried to use `UIAppearance` with this code:

```
UIImage *imgBack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6, 22, -6, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:imgBack forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But this just resulted in a distorted version of the back button that also still showed the `title` of the previous `UIViewController` .

So, my question is **what is the easiest way to globally customize my back button such that it doesnt show the title of the previous `UIViewController` but rather only my custom image?**

**NOTE:** I would like to avoid subclassing `UINavigationController` as well as having to set the back button explicitly within every `UIViewController`, actually the following code will work for this, if placed e.g. in `viewDidLoad`

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 27);

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

So, what I am looking for is a **truely global way to customize the back button exactly once**.

Comment: Did you tried creating your own NavigationController (extending UINavigationController) and personalize it on viewDidLoad?

Comment: This would be an option I guess, but I would like to avoid subclassing `UINavigationController`. I updated the question with a hint on that :)

Comment: From `backBarButtonItem` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/backBarButtonItem) it seems that you can't assign a custom view but only a custom image or title: _When configuring your bar button item, do not assign a custom view to it; the navigation item ignores custom views in the back bar button anyway_. So I think that the only option is to subclass `UIViewController` override `viewDidLoad` and set the `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

Comment: nice, thanks for the hint to the docs... guess I'll have to go with customizing in `viewDidLoad`